# In Django, how do I replace a model's image using a receiver?

Tags: django, image, model

I'm trying to convert images uploaded as part of a model to jpgs on save. My code creates the jpg and deletes the original imag (w.g., a tiff) but I can't get it to replace the image in the model. In other words, if I create an Item x and try to display x.image, nothing is there. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**models.py:**

```
def image_upload(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "{0}.{1}".format(instance.title, ext)
    return os.path.join("originals", filename)

class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=image_upload,
        blank=True,
        validators=[validate_image]
    )

@receiver(post_save, sender=Item)
def image_to_jpg(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created') and instance.image:
        filename, file_ext = os.path.splitext(instance.image.path)
        if file_ext != ".jpg":
            im = Image.open(instance.image.path)
            im = im.convert("RGB")
            im.save(instance.image.path.replace(file_ext, ".jpg"))
            storage, path = instance.image.storage, instance.image.path
            instance.image = im
            storage.delete(path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to have a look at [Django ImageKit library](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit). It handles this logic of processing images to one format on upload for you. For your model you would just do:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = ProcessedImageField(
        upload_to=image_upload,
        blank=True,
        validators=[validate_image], format='JPEG', options={'quality': 80}
    )
```

In the docs you can also see the set of different built-in processors they provide, for example for resizing the image to fit a maximum resolution.

For your concrete answer, I think the problem is just that the changes to the image field are not being saved in the database... you would need to either:

- deactivate the `post_save` signal and call `instance.save()` and then activate it again
- use model's `update()` method

But I think the ImageKit option is more robust and well-tested.

Comment: ImageKit is much simpler and more elegant. Thank you!